# What is data aliasing effect in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I'm planing to use this StatelessSession interface in hibernate. But do not know what data aliasing effect as explained [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/batch.html#batch-statelesssession)

Answer (score 7):

consider data like

```
table parent
id | name
---------
1  | 'foo'

table child
id | parent_id
--------------
1  | 1
2  | 1
```

and a query

```
session.query("from child").list();
```

then the following will fail for `StatelessSession session` but not for `Session session`

```
childs.get(0).getParent().setName("bar");

assertEqual("bar", childs.get(1).getParent().getName());
```

Update:

StatelessSession does not "remember" the objects it loaded so while dehydration the second child it doesn't know it already created the parent object it refers to and will create another parent object which has the same values but not the same references.

Comment: Can you please explain more? I couldn't understand completely. I understand that `StatelessSession` is not associated with persistence context.

Comment: @Keerthivasan IMO that's implementation detail. I'll Update the answer